# KVM and USB devices attachments

Tags: kvm-virtualization

I have not so nice problem with USB devices connection to my VM machine. My situation. I have two identical USB network adapters. I want to connect one of these nics to my VM. So in my situation Product and Vendor ids will not help as they are the same of the both usb devices and its not enough to specify only these things. Ok, so there is another thing when I can use address clause to specify bus number and device number. But there goes another problem - device number gets incremented after each usb device reconnection and possibly will change after host reboot. So what are my options then? Was not able to find out any solution on the internet:(

Comment: could this UL Q/A help you? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/452934/can-i-pass-through-a-usb-port-via-qemu-command-line/452946#452946

Comment: But I'm using virsh(libvirt) for my VM management, not qemu-kvm.

Comment: but: 1/ you wrote in your question "KVM and USB" and nowhere libvirt 2/ libvirt uses KVM and QEMU as backend. If your issue is also about libvirt configuration to use backend features, you should explicitly ask it too.